# Transpose Function

Tags: r

I am looking to transpose the rows into columns using R. Below the data frame I am working with

```
Uniquelabel = "1A" 
PointsEx = c(20.4, 44, "2022-01-01", 900, 22, 50, "2021-01-01", 1000)

PointsDF <- data.frame(id = Uniquelabel, PointsEx = PointsEx)
```

I want to extract 1st & 5th row and make a new column with these values. i.e 20.4 & 22 data points into a new column name "PointA". Similarly extract 2nd and 6th row and make a new column. i.e 44 & 50 into a new column name "PointB". Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: These sample data are not in the proper format and cannot be used by users trying to help. Please reassess the sample data and provide a working sample.

Comment: What is a *list of rows*?

Comment: @Neel please do not share data as images. Edit the output of ``dput(df)`` into your original question (not in the comments), where ``df`` is your 'list of rows'.

Comment: I am still confused about how you want your final dataset to look like. Could you provide code that would demonstrate your desired data?

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it. The output of the below statement is what I am looking for.   PointA = c(20.4, 22)
pointB = c(44, 22)
pointC = c(2022-01-01, 2021-01-01)
pointD = c(900, 1000)

PointOutput <- data.frame(id = c(Uniquelabel),
                       PointA = c(PointA),
                       pointB = c(pointB),
                       pointC = c(pointC),
                       pointD = c(pointD))

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to reshape your data wider. This would be easy if your data were in this format:

```
  id instance   name   PointsEx
1 1A        1 PointA       20.4
2 1A        1 PointB         44
3 1A        1   Date 2022-01-01
4 1A        1      X        900
5 1A        2 PointA         22
6 1A        2 PointB         50
7 1A        2   Date 2021-01-01
8 1A        2      X       1000
```

However you don't, so it's a bit trickier - you might need to create these first, for example with `mutate()`.

```r
PointsDF |>
        dplyr::mutate(name = rep(c("PointA", "PointB", "Date", "X"), 2),
                      instance = rep(c(1, 2), each = 4)) |>
        tidyr::pivot_wider(values_from = PointsEx)
```

```
A tibble: 2 x 6
  id    instance PointA PointB Date       X    
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>
1 1A           1 20.4   44     2022-01-01 900  
2 1A           2 22     50     2021-01-01 1000
```

NB: you would need to adapt the `rep()` calls depending on how many rows do you have.

Comment: So couple of things - when I run this, I get an error message stating x `name` must be size 1, not 16. I don't see any data size is defined here. Any idea why its complaining about it? Also the number of rows would be different for each id in the data set. so ID = 1A has 8 rows, ID = 2A had 12 rows and so on. I am thinking to use a statement rows count. I may be completely off here.

Comment: It's working on my end with the data you provided.

Comment: That's true. Using sample data its working. I am using it in a bigger dataset that has character length up to 12 in the X column. Not sure if that's throwing the error out.